# Shuffle a cartesian product iterator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator, generator, cartesian-product

Using a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/cartesian-product-generator I am able to generate a cartesian product iterator. This is necessary when I have, say 4 arrays, each of length 100, giving 100 million combinations - which is too memory intensive to generate an array of.

However, I want to randomise these 100 million combinations, so that I can iterate over all of them in a random order. How can I randomise the order of iteration without bringing all 100 million items into memory?

Comment: I doubt that's possible, since you'll need to remember which combinations were already generated and which were not

Comment: What are you going to do with the combinations? Are you actually iterating over all of them, or only a part? Why do you need them in random order?

Comment: Each array reflects the coefficients of a possible equation. I want to test out the first 10000 combinations, to find X (e.g. 10) arrays of coefficients that make the equation solvable. If there are not X solvable equations, I'll try the next 10000. Except if I did it sequentially, then the coefficients would all be pretty similar.

TLDR: I want to iterate over parts of the combinations at a time, and if I find the combinations I need before iterating over all of them, I'd like the combinations to be quite different (rather than sequential)

Comment: So you actually don't need to randomise them, you'd be fine with a completely deterministic procedure. You just don't want to test them in strictly increasing order since you feel you get more/better matches otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following trick.

Think of a mapping from elements to numbers.

Given Peters example:

```
// ----------  2    1    0 
const arr1 = ['r', 'g', 'b'];
const arr2 = ['early', 'late'];
const arr3 = ['high', 'low'];
```

You can map arr1 to (0, 1, 2), arr2 to (0, 1) and arr3 to (0, 1).

So a 3 digit number like 201 would encode r-late-high.

But you can transform the mapping to a decimal number, it's `3*2*2`=12 combinations, so your decimal number would require 2 digits or fit into 4 Bits ("1001").

This way, your 12 combinations can be shuffled by generating the numbers 0-11 and by shuffling these. But better: Generate a random number from 0-11 and use an array of bits to mark every combination, which has been seen/tested.

In a trivial case, every array would be of size 10 and you could use the number directly as key for your values. The last digit denotes the element of the last array, the first digit of the first array and so on.

It needs a bit more concentration for working with different array sizes and number below and above 10, but it's simple multiplication/division and modulo operation.

For example, given 3 Arrays of size 212, 7 and 19, you have 212*7*19 = 28196 possible combinations.

You generate `sample=rnd (28196)` and get 13936. Now you take that value modulo 19 `(% arr3.length())` which is 9. So the element at index 9 of the 3rd array is picked.

You take 13936/19 and get 733. 733 % 7 is 5, so this denotes the 5th element of arr2.

`733/7=104, 104%212` is 104 so you pick the 104th element from arr1. This is reproducible and fast. In your bit array, you mark the Bit at index 13936 as true (default: false).

I wrote a similar algorithm not in JS, but Scala, and it is super fast.

If you happen to search nearly your whole array, it will get slow when 99.999% of the array is already marked "true", and repeated random numbers always return an already tested value. Then you might be better off visiting the elements in order or counting the seen elements and only generating a random number from size-count, then iterating over the bit array and skipping all seen bits. You could even start with strategy 1 and switch to the second one when things slow down.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an iterator to randomize the result because you'd need to have all arrays in memory to randomize.

You can however build your own random cartesian product generator:

```js
function randomCartesianProduct() {
  return Object.keys(arguments).map(key => {
    let arr = arguments[key];
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
  });
}

const arr1 = ['r', 'g', 'b'];
const arr2 = ['early', 'late'];
const arr3 = ['high', 'low'];
for(let i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
  let r = randomCartesianProduct(arr1, arr2, arr3);
  console.log(i + ': ' + r.join(', '));
}
```

**UPDATE 1** based on additional requirement to avoid repeating any products:

```js
class RandomCartesianProduct {

  constructor(...args) {
    this.arrays = args;
    this.productSize = this.arrays.reduce((acc, arr) => acc * arr.length, 1);
    this.seen = {};
    this.seenSize = 0;
  }

  next() {
    if(this.seenSize >= this.productSize) {
      return null; // all combinations exhausted
    }
    let result;
    let hash;
    do {
      let idxes = [];
      result = this.arrays.map(arr => {
        let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        idxes.push(idx);
        return arr[idx];
      });
      hash = idxes.join('-');
    } while(this.seen[hash]);
    this.seen[hash] = true;
    this.seenSize++;
    return result;
  }
};

const arr1 = ['r', 'g', 'b'];
const arr2 = ['early', 'late'];
const arr3 = ['high', 'low'];
const random = new RandomCartesianProduct(arr1, arr2, arr3);
for(let i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
  let r = random.next();
  console.log(i + ': ' + r);
}
```

Output: (one of many random ones)

```
1: g,late,low
2: g,late,high
3: g,early,low
4: r,early,low
5: b,early,low
6: r,early,high
7: b,early,high
8: b,late,low
9: g,early,high
10: b,late,high
11: r,late,low
12: r,late,high
13: null
14: null
15: null
16: null
```

A `this.seen` hash tracks already returned random values. The hash is based on the random indexes into arrays, e.g. is relatively short.

Once all combinations are exhausted a `null` is returned.

Keep in mind that running this with many & big arrays will get slower over time because of many retries, e.g. hits on seen items will increase over time.

Comment: This will generate duplicates, not shuffle the cartesian product.

Comment: It's a nice answer but in my particular scenario I need to avoid repeating any products

Comment: I added an **UDPATE 1** on the additional requirement